# Checking Stripe subscription status in 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How is everyone checking their users subscription status in 5.2?

In 5.1 it was easy `$user->subscribed()`, but now you have to specify a plan name as an argument `$user->subscribed('plan-name')`.

To grab the user's plan name, I created a Subscription model to go along with the subscription table that is created by Cashier. Then created an association between User and Subscription, so I can get a user's plan name like `$user->subscription['name']`, then I just inserted that into the subscribed call:

```
$user->subscribed( $user->subscription['name'] )
```

It looks fine to me, and outputs the plan name in Tinker correctly, but ends up breaking things and throwing this error on some of my routes:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::active()

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Actually that [subscription name parameter is optional](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/22ee3be4781d0305e0e033139b2c082c149b1495/src/Billable.php#L71-L80) if you have only one subscription an you name it `default` :). Aside from that could you please post your `User` model class, and perhaps the relevant code from the routes that have the problems. Also, a full stack trace of the error would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, I am using > 1 plan name hence the problem. Thanks for that link, I see they're referencing $this->subscribed, which collides with the model association I created on the user $user->subscribed

Answer (score 1):

Just an issue with the model I created called `Subscription` and it's hasOne association from User called `subscription`. This is a reserved word that was creating a collision, and then the QueryBuilder errors noted in the question.

I simply changed the model name that references the subscriptions table to `StripeSubscription` (include a `$table = 'subscriptions'` property in the Model), and also the association from User to `stripeSubscription`.

Then you're able to call the Cashier function, like:

`$user->subscribed( $user->stripeSubscription['name'] );`